# How do i get the Quote Pricebook2Id from the visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, controller, class, id, parameters

i have a visualforce page and it has the Pricebook lookup in Quote page

Now, how do i get that id from visualforce page to controller because i am going to put that id in where clause in one SOQ ??

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title="Quote Line Item By Group" columns="2">
     <!--<apex:inputField value="{!Quote.CurrencyIsoCode}"/>-->
     <apex:inputField value="{!Quote.PriceBook2Id}" label="Select PriceBook" required="True"/>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: I don't understand. You just have to request this `Pricebook2Id` field in your SOQL query when retrieving the `Quote`. If this a controller.

Comment: i want the id just before saving my quote

Comment: If you're able to display this field in your visualforce page, this is certainly because you have a `Quote` variable in your controller. If the user, modify the `pricebookId` using the field, the `Quote` variable is automatically updated. So if you insert your quote using the `Quote` variable, the pricebook Id will be set.

Comment: Yes that's right but i have a lookup field of `Product` and based on the `quote` `Pricebook` i need to filter the Product

Comment: Controller variables and visualforce inputs are automatically bind. If the user changes the `Quote.Pricebook2Id` input, the controller variable `Quote.Pricebook2Id` is automatically changed. Just use this variable to filter your products.

Comment: ok. you mean i don't need to pass any parameter in visualforce page, just use `Quote.Pricebook2Id` in where clause..right ?

Comment: Exactly ! Of course, if you want to update this list each time the input is changed, you will have to use an [action support](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionSupport.htm).

Comment: is it correct ? `String soql = 'Select Id, Name, PriceBook2Id from Pricebookentry where PriceBook2Id = \'Quote.Pricebook2Id\'';`